# ShinyApp : Connection Reset By Peer

Tags: r, windows-10, shiny

The shinyapp I built earlier was running fine in my old laptop. Recently I got a new laptop with Windows10. After setting up everything, I tried to run the app but it the browser opens and closes immediately with the error :

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5004
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

I have also set chrome as default browser....

I deployed this app in shinyapps.io it is working fine there.

I tried few more simple apps in Rstudio but the same issue coming. Looks like the issue is more related to some setting in Windows10. Can someone help me please.

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 1):

Without details on the specific code, I'd share my personal experience with the same error for your reference. In my case, I used RStudio to create a shiny app that save data to a local directory on my computer, while I told R to output files to directory "response", I hadn't created such directory under the working directory so came the error. Simply creating the sub directory named "response" solve this right away. Or for moving your project files to different places in the future, you can just check whether the folder exists, if not, create one shall save you a lot of time.