# Shiny app getting disconnected from server (trial version of shiny server pro)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, flexdashboard

I have a shiny app which works fine when launched from RStudio but gets a "disconnected from server" error when running on shiny server pro (i tried open source as well as 45 day trial version, this is on RHEL 7.5 VM). The application is reading a few files from the local disk, talking to elastic search and also rendering a leaflet map (so it is a heavy app no doubt) but all this works fine (takes a few tens of seconds to load but thats ok for now) when launched from RStudio, but when launched from the shiny server it disconnects almost immediately after the landing page is rendered.

I am thinking this is because of the app inactivity timeout which is 5s. I have tried to change the following params in /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf but not effect. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
app_init_timeout 300;
app_idle_timeout 300;
app_session_timeout 300;

preserve_logs true;
sanitize_errors false;
sockjs_heartbeat_delay 300;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787153/shinyapp-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721008/error-on-request-read-connection-reset-by-peer-in-r-shiny